# Why does java use an @functionalInterface annotation, instead of a modifier?

Tags: java, annotations, keywords

What were the motivations for java to use the @FunctionalInterface annotation, instead of creating a new FunctionalInterface modifier?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MyFunction {
    TypeB myFunction(TypeA objectA);
}
```

vs.

```
public FunctionalInterface MyFunction {
    TypeB myFunction(TypeA objectA);
}
```

this question is similar to [Question about Override Annotation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327640/why-does-java-use-an-override-annotation-instead-of-a-modifier/327643), but one Comment from Michał Kosmulski about enum being a new entity fits the functional Interface definition.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881826/what-are-functional-interfaces-used-for-in-java-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasoning is the same as for the `@Override` annotation. The concept of *Functional Interface* has always existed in Java. It just didn't have a name. (It used to be informally called *SAM (Single Abstract Method) Interface*.)

So, there were already thousands of *Functional Interfaces* in the real world *before* the actual concept of *Functional Interface* was introduced. For example, the `java.util.Comparator` interface is a [*Functional Interface* in Java SE 13](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) but it [already existed in Java 2 SE 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Comparator.html) and in fact was introduced as early as Java 1.2.

It's not the [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation that makes an interface a *Functional Interface*, it's the fact that it implements the [*Functional Interface* specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8).

Straight from the documentation (**bold** emphasis mine):

> An **informative** annotation type used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a *functional interface* as defined by the Java Language Specification.

and

> However, the compiler will treat **any interface meeting the Definition** of a functional interface as a functional interface **regardless of whether or not a `FunctionalInterface` annotation is present** on the interface declaration.

The presence or absence of the annotation is irrelevant to the interface being a *Functional Interface*. It only does two things:

1. It tells the user of the interface that this is a *Functional Interface*.
2. It tells the compiler to generate an error if the interface violates the *Functional Interface* Specification.

Again, this is a similar situation to the `@Override` annotation. It's not the annotation that makes a method override another, it's the fact that you declare a method with the same name as a method in a supertype.